Print to PDF from Firefox. Text not selectable and not readable. Text is image
How to resolve this challenge?
Steps to reproduce this challenge:

Using Ubuntu 24, using Firefox 127, log-in ebay.ca or ebay.com Then open any eBay "messages" webpage.

Note: Those eBay "messages" webpage includes both HTML text and images. URL starts with https://mesg.cafr.ebay.ca or https://mesg.caen.ebay.ca or https://mesg.ebay.ca This challenge can be reproduced with many other websites. For this example I’m using eBay as many people already have eBay accounts.


Using Firefox, navigate to Option ---> Print. Alternatively, press Ctrl-P keys

Using the "Destination" field. Select "Print to PDF" option. Under "Format" group. Leave the Firefox default "Original" option  selected. Do not select the the other "Simplified" option.

Open the PDF file you created above. Most of the webpage text is not readable, not selectable, not usable. Looks like somehow the HTML text was automatically converted to extremely low resolution images. Those are the challenges. The needed end result is that HTML text print as selectable text into the PDF file. This screenshot below shows this challenge.
This challenge can also be reproduced with this Wikipedia page at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum See this attached PDF file at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=9411073


Using Firefox 127 from https://flathub.org/apps/org.mozilla.firefox.
Using Ubuntu 24. This challenge can also be reproduce with Debian 12 Bookworm.
This challenge can not be reproduced with Ungoogle-Chromium/Chrome. It can only be reproduced with Firefox/LibreWolf.

Related

Similar challenge but without resolution and without workaround at Print to PDF from Firefox and Chromium text is image not selectable

Bug report Firefox at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1906126

Bug report Debian at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=658004



Does this happen to all pages, or only those ebay pages? How about printing this question on Ask Ubuntu?

Thanks for your comment @muru :) Only some websites and some of their pages. Such as eBay, Wikipedia, and many others. Those eBay "messages" webpage includes both HTML text and images. URL starts with https://mesg.cafr.ebay.ca or https://mesg.caen.ebay.ca or https://mesg.ebay.ca This challenge can not be reproduced with this Ask Ubuntu page 1519465

This challenge can also be reproduced when using Firefox to print to PDF this Wikipedia page at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum
See that attached PDF file at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=9411073
This challenge can be reproduced with many other websites. Such as, but not limited to, Wikipedia.Org. But only some of their pages. Not all their pages.

I can't reproduce your problem using the Molybdenum Wikipedia page. I uploaded the resulting PDF here. I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and Firefox 127 the default snap version.

I used the "Original" format, the default option.

Thanks for trying user68186 :) So maybe somehow it depends on both which webpage and something else. The mystery thickens, LOL ;)
We were able to reproduce this challenge with two different devices. And different versions of Firefox. Both with and without add-ons/modules.
This change can be reproduced all the way back to Firefox version 14.0.1 Which was released more than 10 years ago.

I used a fully updated version of Ubuntu 24.04 in a VM with the default version of Firefox that came with it (snap) without any add-ons. I also tried it in PopOS 22.04 (based on Ubuntu 22.04). The Firefox 127 there is not the snap version. In both the PDFs I can select the text and the embedded web links work. I am voting to close this question as "not reproducible".

I'm using the latest Firefox 127 from https://flathub.org/apps/org.mozilla.firefox Not the Snap version. I updated the steps accordingly.
I disagree with "not reproducible". Because so far 3 people were able to reproduce this. Only one not able to reproduce.

Unable to reproduce using Snap Firefox 127 on 24.04. Ebay message text printed to PDF is selectable as text.

1/ install firefox extension, print friendly.  2/ use extension to print to pdf.  3/ install pdf2txt.  4/ use pdf2txt to create a readable text file (note, all formatting is lost).

We found this Temporary workaround:

Using Firefox, navigate to Option ---> Print. Alternatively, press Ctrl-P keys

Using the "Destination" field. Select "Print to PDF" option. Under "Format", select the option “Simplified”.

Open the PDF file. The same text is not selectable. But the images were not all printed as this is a simplified view of the webpage. So it seems that somehow the content of the printed webpage affect the "Print to PDF" output.



Related challenge at Print to PDF from Firefox and Chromium text is image not selectable workaround

Using Firefox, navigate to Option ---> Print. Alternatively, press Ctrl-P keys

Using the "Destination" field. Select "Print to PDF" option. Under "Format", select the option “Simplified”.

Open the PDF file. The same text is not selectable. But the images were not all printed as this is a simplified view of the webpage. So it seems that somehow the content of the printed webpage affect the "Print to PDF" output.


